# Mix Polymorphic associations with STI or MTI in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance, multiple-table-inheritance

I have a problem or dilemma after implementing polymorphic association following [this](https://www.sihui.io/has_many-through-and-polymorphic/): All the code is located [here](https://github.com/anquegi/polymorphic),

I have implemented this model:

[image: model]

Let's suppose that I also need the subscription to magazines. It will also be something similar to the other two

```
class Magazines < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions, as: :subscribable
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :podcasts, through: :subscriptions, source: :subscribable, source_type: 'Podcast'
  has_many :newspapers, through: :subscriptions, source: :subscribable, source_type: 'Newspaper'
  has_many :magazines, through: :subscriptions, source: :subscribable, source_type: 'Newspaper'
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscribable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

It works well, the problem now is ok I can handle like three types of subscription
MagazineSubscription, PodcastSubscription and NewspaperSubscription. The three have the same attributes and same behaviour, but belongs to different model. What happens If after doing that I need some kind of MTI or STI with the subscription classes. i.e. the MagazineSubscription have different behaviour and maybe other attributes. There is an easy way on this to accomplish this new requirement like creating a Subscription class that handles all that the polymorphic association and the other models:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :sti_subscription
  belongs_to :subscribable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user


  def _type=(sType)
     sti_subscrition = sType.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s + "Subscription"
     super(sType.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end
end

class MagazineSubscription < Subscription
  # new behaviour here
end
```

or I must follow something similar to [this](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails-3/) with the Subscription class handling two polymorphic relations, with the subscribable and his descendants
 So my question is when I have used polymorphic association is an easy way to use that to set STI or MTI, or I need to make a new approach